# How do I output values from a 2D array in a table using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops

I need to get my code to output the same table as the example output.

The code first asks for a users inputs and then stores them in an array. Data is also validated upon entry. the months range from January to December and are meant to output all results in a table like the one in the desired output.

My code:

```
string[] salesReps = { "Dave", "Sarah", "Juan", "Gilno" };
string[] months = { "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", 
"Oct", "Nov", "Dec" };
int[,] salesStats = new int[4, 12];

//title
Console.Write("\n\nSales Figures\n");
Console.Write("*******************\n");

//sales
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    Console.Write("\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the sales data for {0}", salesReps[i]);
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(months[j] + ": ");
        //validates entry
        while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out salesStats[i, j]))
        {
            Console.Beep();
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter only valid numbers!");
            Console.Write(months[j] + ": ");
        }
    }
}
```

With the code I already have how would I achieve the desired output?

Desired output:

[image: Desired example output.]

Comment: _After_ you have collected all the data into `int[,] salesStats = new int[4, 12];`, then you will need another (nested) loop to print the results. You will also need to store the names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this fragment of code after `//sales` `for` loop:

```
Console.WriteLine("\nResult:\n");
Console.WriteLine("\t" + string.Join("\t", months)); // Print months row
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < salesReps.Length; i++)
{
    sb.Append(salesReps[i] + "\t"); // Add Name
    for (int j = 0; j < salesStats.Length / salesReps.Length; j++)
        sb.Append(salesStats[i, j] + "\t"); // Add values per montth

    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); // Print to console
    sb.Clear(); // Clear for new row data
}
```

It uses `StringBuilder` class to build rows with `\t` indents for each value of `salesStats`. To make things up without `StringBuilder` usage, replace `sb.Append(...)` with `Console.Write(...)` and leave only empty `Console.WriteLine()` at end of first loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < salesReps.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(salesReps[i] + "\t"); // Print Name
    for (int j = 0; j < salesStats.Length / salesReps.Length; j++)
        Console.Write(salesStats[i, j] + "\t"); // Print values per month at same line in Console

    Console.WriteLine(); // To make line break
}
```

You can "play" with `.PadLeft(int)` value to align items as you wish. I mean for example:

```
salesReps[i].PadLeft(3) + "\t";
salesStats[i, j].ToString().PadLeft(3) + "\t";
```

`3` in that case should be length of max `j` value in string representation, I think (e.g. "4321" - length=4, "78923" - length=5 etc). You can search StackOverflow about how get Max value of in multidimensional array. One of them [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582633/using-linq-to-obtain-max-of-columns-for-two-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Thank you! This was very insightful!

Comment: Mark as helpful if it help you or solved your issue.

Comment: Have done now, thanks for the help!